# add a variable to existing column name in a insert command

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables

I have a question. I have researched this question on stack and other sites and have not found the answer. I would like to have a insert command that attaches a string to the existing column name. I have a table that has the same columns multiple times for different months. Example of columns: **name1** would be January and **name2** would be for February. **address1** would be for January and **address2** would be for February and so on and so forth. the only think i have come across is how to pass a variable into the data for the column, i need to ADD a variable to the already existing column name so i wont have multiple insert commands. here is my code.

```
 If MonthDDL.SelectedValue <> "" Then
        Select Case MonthDDL.SelectedValue  
            Case Is = "January"
                Month = "0"
                monthVar = "January"
            Case Is = "February"
                Month = "1"
                monthVar = "February"
            Case Is = "March"
                Month = "2"
                monthVar = "March"
            Case Is = "April"
                Month = "3"
                monthVar = "April"
            Case Is = "May"
                Month = "4"
                monthVar = "May"
            Case Is = "June"
                Month = "5"
                monthVar = "June"
            Case Is = "July"
                Month = "6"
                monthVar = "July"
            Case Is = "August"
                Month = "7"
                monthVar = "August"
            Case Is = "September"
                Month = "8"
                monthVar = "September"
            Case Is = "October"
                Month = "9"
                monthVar = "October"
            Case Is = "November"
                Month = "10"
                monthVar = "November"
            Case Is = "December"
                Month = "11"
                monthVar = "December"
                'Case Else
        End Select
        selDate = MonthDDL.SelectedValue
    Else
        lblSelect.Visible = True
    End If

DBCONN.Open()
        Dim SqlUpdate = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable = '" + Session("sessionvariable") + "'", DBCONN)

MonthDDL.SelectedValue = monthVar And dr.HasRows = True Then
                SqlUpdateCommd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE table SET [table].[name] '"+ Month +'" = '" & contact & "',[table].[address]'"+ Month +'" = '" + address + "' WHERE variable = '" & Session("sessionvariable") & "'", DBCONN)
        ElseIf MonthDDL.SelectedValue = monthVar And dr.HasRows = False Then
            SqlUpdateCommd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (name '"+ Month +'", address '"+ Month +'", variable) Values ('" + contact + "', '" + address + "', Session("sessionvariable") + "')", DBCONN)
```

is this possible to do. am i even close to going about this the right way. I appologize for phrasing i am new to vb.net. Im not even really sure what to search for that is probably why i havent really stumbled across an answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your code not working?

Comment: Also, I suspect you could make things a lot easier for yourself by improving the design of your table.  I.e. instead of having different column names, why not have the table be [month],[name],[address]? Then you don't have to have multiple name/address columns per row.

Comment: i dont think that will work i have to keep 12 months of data and the data can vary from month to month thats where my other issues comes into play but thats a different story

Comment: Could you post some (de-identified) sample data from your table?  Perhaps using http://sqlfiddle.com?  This will make it much easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Also, what's not working with what you are currently doing in the code?

Comment: my exception error: is Incorrect syntax near '1, address '. im pretty sure im just not going about it the right way...r u saying it should be working?

Comment: Can you post fuller context of the code--it's hard to read as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dwright is correct.  You really shouldn't be doing this because, among other things, if the variable is user definable, it makes your application susceptible to SQL-injection attacks.  It would be far better and simpler to redesign you database schema so that you don't have repeated columns like that.

However, the likely reason why your code is failing is because you are appending apostrophes before and after the variable values, for instance:

```
"[table].[name '" & variable & "']"
```

Notice, that the above statement would actually evaluate to something like this:

```
"[table].[name '1']"
```

But, what you really want, is probably this:

```
"[table].[name1]"
```

So, to get that, you would need to do something like this:

```
"[table].[name" & variable & "]"
```

However, as I said, it's not only a bad idea to build dynamic SQL like this, it's also indicative of a poorly designed database schema.

Comment: i hear ya on the sql injection. but would i be susceptible to that if the variable is defined based on a selected value of a drop down list? and ty for the example on the variable!

Comment: No, in that case, as long as the value is un-editable, SQL-injection is not an issue.  However, it's still ugly, complex, and not a normalized schema.  But, it's not the worst I've seen :)

Comment: i will agree with you on that im not a db guru by any means still a noob to a lot of things but i KNEW this was a bad idea. originally the site was not designed for this and was added much later than our initial design. unfortunately i am not the only one working on this and i can not always get others to agree with my ideas on things :-/ lol. Thanks a lot both of you guys!! good insight!

Comment: Trust me, that's well understood.  Like I said, I've seen, and had to work with designs that were much worse than that :)  Sometimes you just have swallow your pride and just make it work rather than making everything perfect.